# What is meant by "Sense of the World" (TLP)?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein

Wittgenstein defines World as:

> TLP: World is the totality of facts, not of things.

Clearly, Wittgenstein is referring to the mental "representation" of the World, not the physical World itself.

We use the word 'sense' in the following way:

> Human: Does this make *sense* to you...?

This usage captures the true meaning of 'sense': a proposition may be well formed (decipherable according to social/language rules), but are you able to "think" what I am thinking?

> TLP: A thought is a proposition with sense.

Now this is where I am lost:

> TLP: Sense of the World must lie outside the World.

Can the World itself have a sense- Is Wittgenstein still talking about same "sense"?

Even if I agree, how can one just stand away and declare so? Am I not required to "use" some prior sense to be able to make that statement in the first place? Let me be more clear: if sense belongs, so to speak, to a singular faculty of mind -let's call it, for lack of a better term, *understanding*. Now there seems to be something "fundamentally" wrong in being able to make a statement about *sense*: For if there isn't infinite hierarchy of such senses, one cannot safely "use" sense to make a statement *about* sense. More generally, one cannot explain everything, for if one does, the theory itself runs at the danger of being unable to explain itself.

How are we supposed to interpret the "Sense of the World" then (according to TLP / view points against it)? Does/can it exist? If yes, is it "sensible" to us?

Comment: Consider [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/32680/what-does-bedeutung-refer-to-in-the-tractatus-logico-philosophicus) for *sense* and *meaning* into the Tractatus.

Comment: And see [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51115/making-sense-of-wittgensteins-senselessness-nonsense-distinction-in-the-tra) for sense/nonsense.

Comment: And [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41190/what-is-the-relationship-between-what-can-be-said-and-what-cannot-be-said) for "speaking about meaning"

Comment: And [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/35854/the-picture-theory-of-meaning) about "the sense of the world"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parts of *Tractatus* are about language, world and logic.

In order to understand it, we have to consider the background, and mainly [Frege's philosophy of language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#FreLan) where *meaning* is twofold: *bedeutung*, i.e. the objects to which the linguistic expression refers to, and the *sinn*, i.e. the thought that the linguistic expression expresses.

In a nutshell, the basic difference is that for W, names have only reference:

> **2.221** What a picture represents is its sense. [A complex linguistic expression: name-relation, is a fact that pictures a non-linguistic fact. See [W's picture theory of language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#TracLogiPhil).]

> **3.142** Only facts can express a sense, a set of names cannot.

Having said that, in the *Tractatus* there are two way of beig ["devoided of *sense*"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#SensNons): being senseless (*sinnlos*), like logic formulas, that are "syntactically correct" but without meaning, because they do not represent facts, and being nonsensical (*unsinnig*), like the propositions of metaphysics and ethics.

> Traditional metaphysics, and the propositions of ethics and aesthetics, which try to capture the world as a whole, are also excluded, as is the truth in solipsism, the very notion of a subject, for it is also not “in” the world but at its limit.

The final part of the *Tractatus* is about ethics:

> **6.41** The sense of the world must lie outside the world.

Here *sense* is not only the "technical" term derived from Frege, but is roughly: the meaning of life.

And:

> **6.421** It is clear that ethics cannot be put into words. Ethics is transcendental.

In a nutshell, values are not facts of the world and thus they cannot be expressed by "syntactically correct" propositions.

In conclusion, the "meaningful" questions (the scientific ones?) are those related to the *facts* in the world. We can speak of them with our language and thus - in principle - we can answer them.

But there are also questions and problems that remain untouched by science, like ethics and theology. For them, the only approach is "the mystical":

> **6.522** There are, indeed, things that cannot be put into words. They *make themselves manifest*. They are what is mystical.

Comment: According to W's TLP, is the *idea* of Turing Machine "senseless" (sinnlos)? Not the formulae printed by it, but the concept of Turing Machine (or the intuitive notion of computation) itself?

Comment: @Ajax - what is the link with the discussion above?

Comment: Having said that: why not? A computation is the result of a (human) process performed with symbols. Thus, it is a "fact" of the world and we can describe it (Turing did). It is not a "value".

Comment: I am only trying to internalize W's notions by considering extreme cases.

Comment: While it is clear to me that Turing's Machines can be sinnlos, it seems to me, for reasons I am unable to articulate at the moment, that the "notion" of computation is *with* sense. Godel remarked that the notion of computation is in some sense "absolute" : does this not indicate some concrete "sense" associated with computation?